# Is a proof by counterexample considered a proof by contradiction?

Tags: proof-writing

My question is already in the title.

Let us look at some example.

I would like to prove that a game $G(n,m,u)$ does not have a pure Nash equilibrium (PNE), for example. I did it like this: Suppose that the game $G(n,m,u)$ does admit at least one PNE. For some $n=n_0$, $m=m_0$ and $u=u_0$, I construct an example where the game $G(n_0,m_0,u_0)$ does not have a PNE. So, I construct a counterexample but is this a proof by contradiction?

Comment: Maybe, but does it really matter?

Comment: @anomaly: I very much agree about the does it really matter part. A proof is a proof is a proof, and classification seems like a pointless exercise, unless we are looking at technical issues, such as whether one can avoid excluded middle.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I think it does matter, as far as someone learning these different directions of proof is concerned.  When you reach a certain level of comfort with proofs, no it doesn't matter.  But when you are first learning these proof directions, it definitely matters in my opinion.

Comment: If it does not matter, why we give them names then? Does it matter to say I will prove it by induction or I will prove it by contraposition? Suppose you are reviewing a paper and the authors wrote something like "We will prove Theorem 1 by induction ..." but then you found that the proof is a proof by contradiction, what will your comment be as a reviewer? @anomaly

Comment: @Learning I agree with you that it matters.  But just remember when you are reading the other users' comments that they have a different perspective than you.  From the level they are at, they have seen enough to believe that it doesn't actually matter.  This is just a difference of opinion.  But I agree with you that for someone in the beginning stages of learning proof writing, it definitely matters.  So, I'm apologizing for their dismissal of your question.

Comment: Thank you very much @user46944. There is no problem at all. I just write my opinion also.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually, a proof by contradiction of the statement $p \implies q$ is when you assume that the opposite of the desired conclusion is true (i.e., assume the negation of $q$ is true), and follow a few logical implications until you reach a statement that somehow explicitly or implicitly contradicts an initial assumption from the statement $p$.

Meanwhile, a counterexample of the same statement $p \implies q$ is when you say, "Hold on! This statement can't be true, because here is an example where $p$ holds, but $q$ does not."

In proof by contradiction of the statement $p \implies q$, at the end of the day you actually are proving that $p$ implies $q$.  But if you find a counterexample for the statement $p \implies q$, then you are actually disproving the claim $p \implies q$, so applying proof by contradiction to a statement does the opposite of applying proof by counterexample.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a proof by contradiction, I suspect this is not a proof at all

you showed that $\forall (n_0,m_0,u_0), G(n_0,m_0,u_0) $ admits an example which has no PNE's. This is not the same as saying that $G(n_0,m_0,u_0)$ has no PNE's.

**note** This will be a direct proof  if you knew that if for some example $G(n_0,m_0,u_0)$ has no PNE's then $G(n_0,m_0,u_0)$ has no PNE's